# Publishing working paper before submission to peer-reviewed journal

Tags: publications, paper-submission, preprint

Could the fact that I publish a working paper in a WP-series at the institution where I am doing my PhD jeopardise my chance to have it accepted in a peer-review journal? Since I know it might depend on editor/journal, I specify I was leaning towards Energy Policy (Elsevier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Guide for Authors' states the following:

> [...] Submission of an article implies that the work described has not been published previously (except in the form of an abstract, a published lecture or academic thesis, see 'Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication' for more information) [...]
>
> [...] Please note that preprints can be shared anywhere at any time, in line with Elsevier's sharing policy. Sharing your preprints e.g. on a preprint server will not count as prior publication (see 'Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication' for more information). [...]

[Source](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/energy-policy/0301-4215/guide-for-authors)

Additionally, the page 'Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication' states:

> [...] Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication: An author should not in general publish manuscripts describing essentially the same research in more than one journal or primary publication. Elsevier does not view the following uses of a work as prior publication: publication in the form of an abstract; publication as an academic thesis; publication as an electronic preprint. [...]

[Source](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/journal-authors/policies-and-ethics)

To answer your question, you should clearly define what the `WP-series` really is. Is it just a collection of pre-prints or is it a primary publication? That's how you will get the answer you need.

In case of doubt, contact the Editor in advance.